# what is the best way to include different stylesheet in different pages?

Tags: php, html, css, include

In the situation where index page is the root for every request. And based on URL different page are served.

For now we use same name for CSS file as for page to be served.

But this fails where we want to use same CSS for a group of page or we don't want a special CSS for a page common CSS is sufficient

Also array is suggest a solution but it seem to be unmanageable when site pages increase

Comment: same way that based on the URL you're serving different pages, add code in your view to modify the CSS depending on the different parameters.  This will require some kind of mapping, either an array or your DB.

Comment: As I mentioned array after some time becomes unmanagable

Comment: You'll have to have some form of mapping as pages can't just guess what stylesheet to use . . . now the mapping may be adding one more parameter to the url (e.g. style=a, style=b, etc), or the mapping could be via path to the url, etc.  It doesn't have to be a 1:1 mapping of each page to a stylesheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A LUT would be the *fastest* way, although I think you need to seriously re-architect your app.

Anyway on your index page you have some variable $pageName that says which page you want to load. The you can do something like this.

```
$myPages = array(
   "somePage" => array("style_base.css", "custom_style1.css"),
   "otherPage" => array("style_base.css", "awesome_style.css")
   // more pages here
);

foreach( $myPages[$pageName] as $pageStyleSheet ) {
    echo '<link href="' . $pageStyleSheet . '" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Just so you know this is super hacky and if I had to maintain your app, I would probably want to kill you. BUT it is the *fastest* way based on the architecture you described.

### UPDATE

Another idea, but if you keep the stylesheet for every page based on the page name and use @include for the sheets you want to reuse. So for *somePage.css* you could have

```
@include('otherPage.css')
```

That way you can keep reflecting off the page name, but still reuse styles.

Comment: Not the best way as i have used this now we are using some thing between array and same page name stylesheet

Comment: @Champ yeah I figured you were using data reflection parsing the pageName into your stylesheet name. But like you said, if you want to re-use stylesheets, you have problems. With above at least your LUT is centralized AND you can easily include whatever styles you want. But its super hacky, so depends on your needs

Answer (score 1):

@Champ - You can use a CSS file for the whole web site - use classes etc. These files are very small in comparison to an image. We are talking ASCII and tens of kilobytes (at most) - and that can be cached!

**EDIT**

Use that extra server load instead of PHP to determine the CSS stuff for better things

Comment: Size is not the only problem. What about updating or adding a new page

Comment: The people maintning site are not much experiance and updates are regular

Comment: @champ - Size if not the problem. Just bung in identifies for a particular page that has a particular format. Otherwise use a CMS.